# Create hsqldb database only once per war deployment

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I need to migrate my Spring Application Database from MySql to HSQL database. I configured hsql db details in my xml file and could able to run the sql file and sucessfully connect to it. Hear the issue is when ever i restart my tomcat server, new database is creating and old db is getting deleted. I am looking all the data which i stored in my tables. How can i create db for HSQL only once at the time of war deployment or only once per tomcat restart.

Hear is my configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd">


  <jdbc:embedded-database id="dbcpDataSource" type="HSQL">
      <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
 </jdbc:embedded-database> 

<tx:annotation-driven/>
      <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test"/> 
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100000"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="16000"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
</bean>    
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dbcpDataSource"/>
         <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.design.model"/>
          <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
         </property>
        <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory"><value>false</value></property>

   </bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an HSQLDB server outside your web application with a mem: database named `memdb`. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_server_props and connect to this server with `<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/memdb"/>`. The data remains until to close the external server.

Comment: I used even In memory Configuration either, My requirement is when external server restarted, then also my database should not created. It need to create only once (i.e the first time we deploy the war)

Comment: In that case, use a `file:` database in the server to persist the data.

Comment: Even after using file, its giving the same issue.
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:c:\javasrc\hsqldb-dev:test;ifexists=true;create=false"/>

Comment: Your file: URL is not right.`"jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:\javasrc\hsqldb-dev\test;ifexists=true"`